# Is there any way to tell the compiler that any shared library or executable involved in a process has been build for a certain architecture?

Tags: linux, g++, avx512

I assume the following:

1. calling into a function, which does not reside in the current object file, the compiler needs to consider that this called function was (likely) not built for the same architecture and do such nasty things as VZEROUPPER and cannot keep things in registers meanwhile.

Is there any way to tell the compiler, that this is not the case?

So that the compiler can assume, that all shared libraries (potentially except certain system libraries) are build for the same architecture and that there is no need for VZEROUPPER when calling into code located inside another shared object.

I think this can partially be accomplished by building with -flto. But I'm not certain how to accomplish this for shared libraries.

Comment: GCC has a `-mno-vzeroupper` option, but the x86-64 SysV calling convention still has no call-preserved vector regs.  Unlikely you can convince it to keep anything in vector regs across a call in any sane way; `__attribute__((ms_abi))` has a lot of call-preserved XMM registers (too many, even), but that's literally only the low 16 bytes, not the full register.  If you try using `-mno-vzeroupper`, make sure you profile with `perf stat` for SSE/AVX transition stalls on calls to standard library functions. (Or false dependencies on Skylake-family; Ice Lake is IIRC like Haswell, with a state trans)